# XML parsing error - Start tag expected, '<' not found

Tags: xml, xslt

I am very new for XML... during writing xml.. I have below error for last line. 
'XML parsing error - Start tag expected, '<' not found"

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE fda-regional:fda-regional SYSTEM "http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/static/eCTD/us-regional-v3-3.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/static/eCTD/us-regional">
<fda-regional:fda-regional dtd-version="3.3" xml:lang="text" xmlns:fda-regional="http://www.ich.org/fda" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xlink">
<fda-regional:fda-regional>
 <m1-regional>
 </m1-regional>
 <m1-administrative-information-and-prescribing-information>
  <m1-2-cover-letter>
            ....
  </m1-2-cover-letter>
  <m1-14-labeling>
   ....
  </m1-14-labeling>
     <m1-20-general-investigational-plan>
      ....
  </m1-20-general-investigational-plan>
 </m1-administrative-information-and-prescribing-information>
</fda-regional:fda-regional>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML is not well-formed. it has two issues: (1) `<?xml-stylesheet` line is not closed correctly. (2) I commented out a line without a closing tag.

Just compare your original XML with the XML below.

> XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE fda-regional:fda-regional SYSTEM "http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/static/eCTD/us-regional-v3-3.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/static/eCTD/us-regional"?>
<fda-regional:fda-regional dtd-version="3.3" xml:lang="text"
                           xmlns:fda-regional="http://www.ich.org/fda"
                           xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xlink">
    <!--<fda-regional:fda-regional>-->
    <m1-regional>
    </m1-regional>
    <m1-administrative-information-and-prescribing-information>
        <m1-2-cover-letter>....</m1-2-cover-letter>
        <m1-14-labeling>....</m1-14-labeling>
        <m1-20-general-investigational-plan>....</m1-20-general-investigational-plan>
    </m1-administrative-information-and-prescribing-information>
</fda-regional:fda-regional>
```